# Can statement prepared with sqlite3_prepare_v2 be used with a different connection?

Tags: ios, sqlite, prepared-statement

I am using multiple read-only database connections to the same database within the same process (from different threads). However, I have static `sqlte3_stmt` statements that I use with the passed database connection.

Is it safe to re-use statements prepared this way with different database connection instances (to the same read-only database)? In practice this seems to work, but I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do.

Comment: Why do you have multiple connections? Just open the database once and reuse that single `sqlite3 *` reference. Then you can safely keep a single reference to a prepared statement with that connection.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "use with the passed database connection"? Show that code.

Comment: @CL. So essentially I've created a connection pool of read only connections. I have around 20 connections I re-use. I don't open / close connections because there's a lot of initialization involved (I have a ton of custom sqlite functions that I register when opening a new connection). I re-use these connections in multiple threads. This allows the app to remain responsive as it can read from multiple threads at the same time, given each is a read-only connection. However my prep-statements are held in a global, static array that I share between these threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A statement always uses the connection that it was prepared for (in the call to `sqlite3_prepare*()`. It is not possible to change a statement's connection.

When you use the same statement from multiple threads, all threads share the same cursor, and the same connection, *and the same transaction*. This will blow up eventually.

If you want to save statements, you must use a list of statements per connection.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I wanted to know. Will create a statement cache per database connection then.